# PHP is not printing anything

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a html file with php in it that is suppose to be querying a MYSQL database for information about the top 25 players with their kills deaths etc.
However the page keeps loading blank and I cannot work out what is wrong.
The database does have plenty of entries into it.
The server hosting this file also does have PHP installed.
Could someone please show me where the issue is or tell me what could be causing this issue?
Cheers
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   require_once( "connect.php" );

   $select_top_25 = "
      SELECT     `stats_players`.`name`,
                 `stats_total_pvp_kills`.`times`, 
                 `stats_total_deaths`.`times` 
      FROM       `stats_players`
      INNER JOIN `stats_total_pvp_kills`
      BY         `stats_players`.`player_id` = `stats_total_pvp_kills`.`player_id`
      INNER JOIN `stats_total_deaths`
      BY         `stats_players`.`player_id` = `stats_total_deaths`.`player_id`
      ORDER BY   `stats_total_pvp_kills`.`times` ASC LIMIT 25";

   $result = mysqli_query($link, $select_top_25) or die (mysqli_error($link));

   $counter = 0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   {

       $counter = $counter + 1;
       print '#'.$counter;
       print 'Name: '.$row[0];
       print 'Kills: '.$row[1];
       print 'Deaths: '.$row[2];

   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Blank page can be PHP error - are there any errors in your log file? What do you see when viewing the source (right click in browser -> view page source)?

Comment: I myself am not checking the page. Someone else is so I am not able to view the page source. I thought PHP would display an error?. I will ask them to check the log file now

Comment: Yes, a blank page most likely means there was an error. Check your PHP error log or activate error reporting to see the errors on the page. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your file.

Comment: I have just been told the error log is empty. Also using the error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors", 1); is not displaying errors.

Comment: is it filename.html file or filename.php? because you said that "I have a html file with php in it"

Comment: Try var_dumping` $result`, `$link` and ` $select_top_25`.  You are sure `$link` is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace ***BY*** with ***ON*** like this:

```
SELECT     `stats_players`.`name`, 
           `stats_total_pvp_kills`.`times`, 
           `stats_total_deaths`.`times` 
FROM       `stats_players`
INNER JOIN `stats_total_pvp_kills`
ON         `stats_players`.`player_id` = `stats_total_pvp_kills`.`player_id`
INNER JOIN `stats_total_deaths`
ON         `stats_players`.`player_id` = `stats_total_deaths`.`player_id`
ORDER BY   `stats_total_pvp_kills`.`times` ASC LIMIT 25
```

This could help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally for such case, when you are not sure whats the actual error you should debug script step by step and at there the first thing here you need to check is, echoing any simple text before doing any mySql stuff.

Means before including *connect.php* you should do `echo 'hii'; exit;` and run it. if its display correctly then you can move ahead to check on my sql query and result

Possible cases here for an issue are

1. You have saved file with `html` extension and not with `PHP` extension
2. There is no result coming with you mysql query because of any reason

Comment: im not the downvoter but i guess sometimes there are people who simply downvote for no reason. maybe they to lazy to even read the answere so they just tab downvote. I'll vote it up because in the end its right!

Answer (score -1):

Possible reasons for this:

- Your file is a `.html` and not a `.php` file
- You dont have a apache running (*if its local*)
- You dont have it in the right directory (*if its local and apache is running*)
- Soemthing is wrong with the fileinclude (*connect.php*)
- No DB connection
- Variable `$link` is not set
- Your mysql syntax is wrong ( its **INNER JOIN ... ON ...** not **BY** )
- Your mysql has no result
- No errors are showing up because of `php.ini` setup